# Problems understanding sum notation for a particular partial sum of a infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

I'm solving some Stewart Calculus exercises and the notation for this particular partial sum seems just plain wrong for me, I can't make sense out of it. Maybe the publisher made some mistake.

My textbook says:

$\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{2}{(i-1)(i+1)} = (1 - \frac{1}{3}) + (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}) + ... + (\frac{1}{n-3} - \frac{1}{n-1} ) + (\frac{1}{n-2} - \frac{1}{n})$

However, as the term ($\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n+1}$) is missing at the end ( for $i = n$ ), the partial sum above should be represented by $\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} \frac{2}{(i-1)(i+1)}$ instead of 
$\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{2}{(i-1)(i+1)}$.

Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right; the book is wrong ... they probably meant $\sum_{i=2}^{\color{red}{n-1}} \frac{2}{(i-1)(i+1)}$

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

Since $$\frac{2}{(i-1)(i+1)}=\frac{1}{i-1}-\frac{1}{i+1}$$

We have 
\begin{align}\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{2}{(i-1)(i+1)}&=\sum_{i=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{i-1}-\frac{1}{i+1}\right) \\
&=\left(1-\frac13 \right)+\ldots + \left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1} \right)\end{align}

and

\begin{align}\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{2}{(i-1)(i+1)}&=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{i-1}-\frac{1}{i+1}\right) \\
&=\left(1-\frac13 \right)+\ldots + \left(\frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n} \right)\end{align}